# Sim900 arduino shield on Raspberry

Tags: pi-3, gsm

Just bought this GSM module that is suppose to support raspberry pi
but i cant seem to find any wire up tutorial.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/253162539156

Can someone give a help?

btw: i'm looking for a way to send http post and get requests from this module using nodejs.

Comment: That is an Arduino shield and is not a great deal of use with a Raspberry Pi (it is designed to plug into an Arduino).  I expect you could use it with the Pi but you would need to do quite a bit of work working out which pins to connect where and then writing software to drive them properly.   I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I've had that board (or one very similiar, looking closely I think there may be some differences) working with the Pi.  As far as I'm aware, there isn't even documentation for using it with an Arduino, but I'd concurr with joan: What you have to do before you get to sending web data is not worth it, particularly if you are new to electronics.   Get a USB GSM dongle instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, of course it is usable with the raspberry pi. This module communicates over the serial connection UART (raspberry pi gpio14/15) and i worked with different modules with raspberry pi and arduino.

First you should read the datasheet, containing necessary information for work with:

http://www.vis-plus.ee/pdf/SIM900-DS_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf

AT commands:

https://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf

So from now you have 2 possibilities:

1. Possibility

you create a ppp0 interface in ifconfig

```
sudo apt-get install ppp
```

i wrote a bash script

https://github.com/bierschi/ppp-daemon/blob/master/ppp_config.sh

the important settings are under:

```
/etc/ppp/peers/gprs
```

and

```
/etc/chatscripts/gprs
```

you can find a lot of information by searching on your own with google.

2. Possibility

You take a serial communication package like pyserial in python or other languages. 
Then you communicate with AT commands to the serial port:

https://github.com/JFF-Bohdan/sim-module

There are a few python modules in this repo for the sim900 module, so try on your own